# problem with find xargs and tar concatenation

Tags: find, tar, xargs

I want to store all the png files in a directory tree.
I used

```
 find . -iname *.png| xargs   tar -czf renderresultsall.tar.gz
```

but I get only a part of the files, some directories are missing
e.g.

```
 ./pathA/patha1 ok
 ./pathA/patha2 ignored
 ./pathA/patha3 ok
 ./pathB/pathb1 ignored
 ./pathB/pathb2 ignored
 ./pathB/pathb3 ignored
 ...
```

While if I use:

```
 find ./pathA/ -iname *.png| xargs   tar -czf renderresultspathA.tar.gz
```

I get all the paths (patha1,patha2,patha3) in the path patha

Is it a curse or?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I used `touch` to create files named `pathA/patha{1..3}.png` and `pathB/pathb{1..3}.png`. Then I ran `find . -iname *.png | xargs tar czf renderresultsall.tar.gz`. Running `tar tf renderresultsall.tar.gz` lists all six png files as expected. Please provide an MWE.

Comment: Same here on Archlinux. I cannot reproduce that behavior you describe. /1/  Make sure you do not alias yr `find` cmd to anything at all. In the unlikely case where you'd have a default alias for `find`, issue yr cmd as `\find ...` instead of `find ...`.  /2/ an you tell us about yr  OS + shell ?  /3/ What is the output of `\find . -iname *.png` ?

Comment: This may not be the problem, but please quote `'*.png'`. It could be useful to show separately just the out of find (which you can redirect to a file), and, if as expected, just the output of tar from that file.

Comment: Thanks @dhag. I did that and they differ ... the commands are running on a remote HPC cluster..

Comment: Don't use xargs here. If it runs tar more than once, each run will overwrite the output file. Instead, see [tar archiving that takes input from a list of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033857/tar-archiving-that-takes-input-from-a-list-of-files)

Comment: thanks @MarkPlotnick it worked..  find . -iname *.png |   tar -czf renderresultsall3.tar.gz -T -